# How to access internals from class references via interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have the situation that i have two classes living in different assemblies. `Assembly B` references `Assembly A` and `Class B` needs access to an internal method of `Class A` (internal so that other users of `Class A` dont have access, not for security, just to prevent misuse). I control both assemblies, so [InternalsVisibleTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/assemblies-gac/friend-assemblies) is [possible](http://codesnippets.fesslersoft.de/use-the-assembly-internalsvisibleto-attribute/)  to only grant `Class B` access.

**Assembly A**

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("B")]
public Class A {
...
    internal String secretKey { get; set;}
}
```

**Assembly B**

```
public Class B {
...
    // use A.secretKey which works just fine
}
```

Actually, ***was*** possible because i now need to reference `Class A` via a newly added (actually autogenerated by Visual Studio) Interface `IA`.

**Assembly A**

```
public interface IA {
    // nothing gets generated for secretKey because its internal
}

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("B")]
public Class A : IA {
...
    internal String secretKey { get; set;}
}
```

**Assembly B**

```
public Class B {
...
    // how to use IA.secretKey 
}
```

So the question is, how can i still grant access to the internal method of `Class A` to only `Class B` but not expose it in the interface `IA`? Is this a nogo or what is best practise?

Is [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920868/7926064) an option and [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1259235/7926064) would i apply it? This is not a unittest/mock scenario, but would [PrivateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject(v=vs.140).aspx) fit nevertheless? [Dynamic assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14498568/7926064) loading?

Totally different approaches welcome!

Comment: You'd just cast to `A` within `B` - the same as you'd have to do even within assembly A. Basically, you want access to a member which is declared on a class, not on the interface, so you need to cast to the class type.

Comment: something like (B as A).secretKey?

Comment: No, I'd use a cast rather than `as`, but it's not clear what you're trying to cast here. You'd need an instance - you haven't shown that in any of your code. But if you had `IA instance = ...;` you'd use `((A) instance).secretKey;`. Note that this is fragile - if anything else implements your interface, the code will break.

Comment: note that `internal` provides absolutely no degree of security, if that's what you have in mind.. you should encrypt your key. (internal member can be easily accessed by reflection, and can be found in memory by hackers.)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary thanks, security is not the reason, i updated the question. Can you show me how to get to the value via reflection? This might be a possible solution.

Comment: Why would you use reflection when casting provides more compile-time safety?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, i will give casting a try, i dont prefer reflection over your suggestion, i just like to keep as many options as possible open

Comment: Note that `InternalsVisibleTo` grants access to all internal members of all classes in assembly A, to all members of assembly B, not just "internal method of Class A to only Class B".